# Reducing time complexity to O(1)

Tags: java, algorithm, math, time-complexity

I coded a program that prints the number of numbers between 1 and d that can be divided by 4 differents ints: k, l, m, n. This has a time complexity of O(d). But I read that you can do the same thing with the time complexity of O(1), and I have no clue how.

```java
int k = in.nextInt();
int l = in.nextInt();
int m = in.nextInt();
int n = in.nextInt();
int d = in.nextInt();

int sum = 0;
int i = 1;
while (i <= d) {
    if (i % k == 0 || i % l == 0 || i % m == 0 || i % n == 0) {
        sum++;
    }
    i++;
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: Where did you read that?

Comment: Here first paragraph https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/3819  @EJoshuaS

Comment: Are you familiar with the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)? Start by considering a simpler case of the same problem. For example, how many integers between 0 and 1000 are divisible by 2 or 3?

Comment: @Brian Yes I'm familiar with this principle since I also study math at University but i don't understand how that would decrease the time complexity.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose for each number `i`, you have a set `S_i` shows the numbers in `[1, d]` that are multiplier of `i`. Now we want to compute the size of the union of `S_l, S_k, S_m, S_n`. It is equal to

|S_l U S_m U S_n U S_k| = |S_l| + |S_m| + |S_n| + |S_k| - |S_l ∩ S_m| - |S_l ∩ S_n| - |S_l ∩ S_k|- |S_m ∩ S_n| - |S_m ∩ S_k| - |S_n ∩ S_k| + |S_l ∩ S_m ∩ S_n| + |S_l ∩ S_m ∩ S_k| + |S_l ∩ S_n ∩ S_k| + |S_m ∩ S_n ∩ S_k| - |S_l ∩ S_m ∩ S_n ∩ S_k|.

The only point that you need is the intersection size of two or multiple set here is equal to the `d/lcm` that lcm is the least common multiplier of the corresponding numbers of the set.
For example, size of |S_l ∩ S_m ∩ S_n ∩ S_k| is equal to `d/lcm(l,m,n,k)`. Because, if a number is dividable by multiple number, it must be dividable by their lcm. Hence, the number of multiplier of their lcm in `d` can be counted by `d/{lcm of the corresponding numbers}`.

Now, if you can assume that computing `lcm` can be done in `O(1)`, then you can find the size of |S_l U S_m U S_n U S_k| in `O(1)` as well.